# Why is WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE part of App Service Configuration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-appservice

For some reason, all our Azure app services configuration have this WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE = true and I cannot seem to see why/how it is set. I have not explicitly added it to the configuration, and I believe it is a recent change, which was not there previously.
Maybe the release pipeline is adding them, but cannot find any references there to WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE.
Does anyone know if Azure for some reason has begun adding it to configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet#deployment) and [GitHub](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#ensure-update-site-and-update-siteconfig-to-take-effect-synchronously), `WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE` is the default setting configured while deploying the application using `Azure devops` or by `ARM template`.

By default the value is set to 1.

When we have App setting `WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE` as 1, the application will not continue with the deployment process unless and until  all the application settings are updated.

- Once all the app settings are updated, the app will restart and continues with the deployment process.
- I have tried to deploy the web App to Azure App service with `ARM template` using the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-arm-template?pivots=platform-linux).

[image]

- I didn't find and app setting with `WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE` added in the app settings.

[image]

- I have tried with Azure Devops pipeline as well.
  [image]

[image]

- You can see the similar issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25356) which is not yet resolved.
- Follow the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/109471) which I have raised and [SO Thread](https://serverfault.com/a/1060240) for more details.